# Webbrowser: simulate mouse click on ul-li item in webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, jquery, browser

I'm automating process with one website using WebBrowser component C#/.Net
The actual problem is that I do not know Javascript well to understand how things work under the mouse clicks on some elements.

For example, I have a page where ajax and jquery used (I guess so ;)
and there is a list of elements (it is a tree with subtrees).
So when I click on the root element, loading progress is shown and content is changing without complete reload of the page. And subtree is also expanded.

The question is how to do This mouse click on root tree element using WebBrowser control?
I can get aprropriate `<LI>` element for this root elem in the tree and there is a `<span>` with text only.
If I call `InvokeMember("click")` it does nothing...

please advise..

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the web browser control a `winforms` control? Are we talking about making a `winforms` program to traverse an html document? Traversing the document with C# isn't going to work with jQuery answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simulate a event on any element.
both of these will work.

```
$(selector).click(); // triggers a click event on the selector (Selectors are CSS like selector passed)
```

#### EDIT:

I don't understand yet from where you are starting to look for that `li`

```
$("li:has(span)").trigger("click"); // triggers a click event on the `li`
```

Comment: But how it detects which one li it should actually click?

Comment: do you know "any" elements (with a class or id) from were to start? if yes, its easy to traverse up or down and reach that `<li>`

Comment: Yes, I know how to reach that <li> element. And if I do elem.InvokeMember("click") nothing happens

Comment: Ok, I found required <span> which is responsible of mouse clicks. Thank you, guys!